# Python: Converting a list of lists of numbers to a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists of numbers in this form:

```
    [[2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [2]]
```

I want this list to be converted to:

```
    ['2 3 4', '0 2 3 4', '1 3 4', '1 2 4', '2']
```

How do I go about it?

Comment: where is your code, what is the [mre], what is the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension like so

```py
my_list = [[2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [2]]

formatted = [" ".join(map(str, x)) for x in my_list]

print(formatted)
```

Prints

```
['2 3 4', '0 2 3 4', '1 3 4', '1 2 4', '2']
```

Comment: the question is probably a duplicate. found the duplicate in 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over all sublists in the list, then join the sublist into the string and append it to the new list. The code would look like this:

```
list = [[2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [2]]
result = []

for sublist in list:
    result.append(" ".join(map(str, sublist))) # join accepts only string lists, so you need to convert the sublist into the list of integer which is achieved via map function
```

Now `print(result)` will output:

```
['2 3 4', '0 2 3 4', '1 3 4', '1 2 4', '2']
```